# Why does gridview dropdownlist selectedIndex is always 2 (Not even 0 or 1 or 3) on selectedIndexChange?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I bind a dropdown list in GridView on `gv_RowDataBound`. During `gv_onSelectionIndexChanged`,

the selected index is always 2 which is the third value in the dropdown list in spite of choosing any other value.

I have tried getting index value, selected value or selected item, it is always index 2.

[Gridview Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNXaB.png)

[Gridview Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPhLp.png)

[Code for onRowDataBound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxuaa.png)

[Code where I am trying to get DropDownList selected value or index or anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xNfe.png)

' Font-Size="Small"
                                    Width="40px">
                                
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                ' Font-Size="Small"
                                    Width="40px">
                                
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                ' Font-Size="Small"
                                    Width="210px">
                                
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                ' Font-Size="Small"
                                    Width="50px">
                                
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                ' Font-Size="Small"
                                    Width="40px" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#CCCCCC">

protected void gvBillOfLadings_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {    
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlBLDescription");
            //ddl.DataSource = your_data_source_here;
            //ddl.DataBind();

            // Populate Bill Of Ladings Choose Description dropdownlist
            String customerIDSession = Session["CustomerID"] != null ? Session["CustomerID"].ToString() : null;
            String connStrLogo = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStrLogo);                
            string getBLDescriptions = "SELECT Description, Class FROM COMMODITY WHERE customerID = '" + customerIDSession + "' ORDER BY Description";

            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt_BLDescriptions = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adpatpter_BLDescriptions = new SqlDataAdapter(getBLDescriptions, conn);
            adpatpter_BLDescriptions.Fill(dt_BLDescriptions);
            ddl.DataSource = dt_BLDescriptions;

            ddl.DataTextField = "Description";
            ddl.DataValueField = "Class";
            ddl.DataBind();
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("CHOOSE DESCRIPTION", "0"));
            conn.Close();
            // End of populating Bill of Lading Items Gridview Description

        }

    }
```

protected void ddlBLDescription_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);
        DropDownList duty = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ddlBLDescription");
        String Text = duty.SelectedItem.ToString();


        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

        Session["slectedValue"] = ddl.SelectedIndex;

        //GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;

        String zero = ddl.Items[0].Text;
        String one = ddl.Items[1].Text;
        String two = ddl.Items[2].Text;
        String three = ddl.Items[3].Text;

        DropDownList list = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlBLDescription");
        String val = list.SelectedValue;
        String item = list.SelectedItem.ToString();

        TextBox txtDesc = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Description");
        txtDesc.Text = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;

        TextBox txtClass = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Class");
        txtClass.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;

    }
```

Comment: Please post your aspx markup as well.

Comment: Jamshaid Kamran I have added images from my code